# Weird spike on simple LED strip controlled using 555 timer and IRF540N MOSFET

Tags: pspice

I'm trying to create an amateur LED strip simulation using a simple 555 timer stable multivibrator configuration. When I'm simulating the circuit on Pspice and measuring the voltage of the LED, I get a weird upward spike on the falling edge of the waveform as it goes to low. Can I have any explanations as to why?

[image]

[image]

Edit: I've added a two bypass caps (47u and 100n) on the supply rail of the 555 timer but the spikes on the LED are worse. I'm quite an amateur so I don't quite understand whats going on

[image]

Comment: Well, so zoom in on it, is it a circuit stray? (Do any of the device models include package inductance?) Is it a numerical artifact (single or alternating time step(s))? What's the rise/fall time?

Comment: it's not the (lack of) bypass caps that are responsible for the spikes. The spikes are, as explained in my answer, due to the switched load having a reactive component! and you really didn't zoom in, but zoomed out… look at the spikes *in much more detail*. I'm sure you'll manage!

Answer (score 0):

That's probably going to be the inverse voltage overshoot from suddenly capping current through a component with (parasitic) reactive impedance, i.e., *ringing*. Zoom in a lot and you should see something that looks round-ish (assuming your simulation time is fine-grained enough).

So, simulation does what it should: simulate the circuit you designed – it just incorporates an effect you might have forgotten about.

---

Word of advice: 5V is for most practical applications too low a supply voltage for the bipolar NE555; you for a CMOS555 if you want to have enough headroom to successfully drive a logic-level MOSFET (and then you can also use a lower, less "awkward" supply voltage than 5V). Also, you forgot the decoupling cap on the supply pin of the 555, don't do that.

Comment: I agree that a modern Cmos 555 should be used. The antique NE555 has a TTL output that draws almost 400mA of "shoot-through" current from the power supply each time it switches that might load the +5V then suddenly unload it causing the +5V to produce the voltage spike. The circuit is missing an important supply bypass capacitor that might reduce the voltage spike.

Comment: @Audioguru I've added two bypass caps on the supply rail but the voltage spikes seem to worsen?

Comment: @Kid The voltage source is most likely defined as fixed voltage, so bypass is meaningless -- you will need to look at nodes inbetween +V and GND to find an explanation. A reminder that SPICE is a simulated environment, a numerical equation-solver that only knows what has been entered into it; and which isn't always perfectly reasonable, as equations can be arbitrarily difficult to solve.

Comment: With a 5V supply, the output if an old NE555 goes to  only+3.7V. But some IRF540 Mosfets need a higher gate voltage. Use a logic-level ORL540 instead.